# How to use wp:featuredmedia in WP REST API response?

Tags: json, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to get blog posts from another WordPress site, as of now I am successfully fetching the posts, I am using the following snippet:

```
$response = wp_remote_get( add_query_arg( array(
    'per_page' => 1,
     'categories' => 38
     ), 'https://www.remotesite.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?_embed' ) 
);
if( !is_wp_error( $response ) && $response['response']['code'] == 200 ) {

   $remote_posts = json_decode( $response['body'] ); 
    foreach( $remote_posts as $remote_post ) {
    echo '<h2>'. $remote_post->title->rendered . '</h2>
           <p>' . $remote_post->excerpt->rendered . '</p>';     

   }
 }
```

with the above code, I can fetch all the required details, title, excerpt, and Featured Image. But I am having a very hard time to find how to get the Featured Image url from the above response. Can anyone tell me how to use the wp:featuredmedia from the response. I have seen somewhere the below code to get the featured image URL, but this won't helped me:

```
echo [your-data]._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].source_url
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Based on your code, the featured image URL can be retrieved like this:

```
$remote_post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}[0]->source_url
```

That is, however, the full-sized version of the featured image file.

To get the URL of a specific thumbnail size, you can access if from:

```
$remote_post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}[0]->media_details->sizes
```

.. which is an `array` of `object` data (unless of course you use `true` in the *second* parameter of the `json_decode()` function).

By default, the available thumbnail sizes are: `thumbnail`, `medium`, and `medium_large`. Here's an example for the `medium` size:

```
$remote_post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}[0]->media_details->sizes->medium->source_url
```

So try this `foreach`:

```
foreach( $remote_posts as $remote_post ) {
    $thumb_full_url = '';
    $thumb_url = '';

    if ( ! empty( $remote_post->featured_media ) && isset( $remote_post->_embedded ) ) {
        $thumb_full_url = $remote_post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}[0]->source_url;
        $thumb_url = $remote_post->_embedded->{'wp:featuredmedia'}[0]->media_details->sizes->medium->source_url;
    }

    echo '<h2>'. $remote_post->title->rendered . '</h2>' .
        '<p>' . $remote_post->excerpt->rendered . '</p>' .
        '<p>' .
            'Medium-sized thumbnail: ' . $thumb_url . '<br>' .
            'Full-sized / source: ' . $thumb_full_url .
        '</p>';
}
```